# How to hold submitted form data until it's been reviewed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a fairly new to ROR.  I'm trying to build my first web app as an experiment which is a job posting site.  The largest feature and pretty much the only feature is to have a user create a posting, review it then pay for it before it is posted.

I ran the scaffold command to get the basic CRUD operations.  This is where I get stuck (yeah I know not that far).  I need to basically tell the app not to submit but hold the data till it has been reviewed and payment has been made, then submit it.  It's sort of like a shopping cart but not really, since a company would be making the "product" then buying it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so looks like your job posting can be in different states:

- draft
- final version (after reviewed)
- posted (after payment)

You might need more than one resource, at least that's how I would do it.

For insight, check [StackOverflow careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv) where you edit your CV as a  **draft** until you reach the **final version_** and then you file it (**post**)